# How to run .pls file in android app using mediaplayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have one `.pls` file which is online but when I am creating media player in my code, it gives error.

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse("PLS file link"));
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Please help me to run `.pls` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android `MediaPlayer` class can not process .pls files directly - it can only play individual media files.

If you want to use a .pls file you will need to download it, read the contents in code and pass each of the URLs to the `MediaPlayer` one at a time.

Comment: if i want to run it then any other option for that ?

Comment: @VatsalShah : No, there are no Android sound classes that can process .pls files. It isn't difficult, a .pls file is just a text file. All you need to do is download it and read the contents.

Comment: do you have any reference link or example ?

Comment: @VatsalShah : This is wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_(file_format) - open your own .pls file with a text editor and compare it to the explanation there.

Comment: but in that if there will be multiple link then how we can get that link ? because the structure will be too complicated to differentiate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(link));
mediaPlayer.start();
```

This piece of code will help you in running .pls link directly through MediaPlayer class.